# Type number[][] is not assignable to type number[]

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to return an array of numbers by a *key* property using `.filter` and `.map`:

```
public getDefaultValues(key: string): number[]{

    let options = [
    {
        key: 'cl',
        values: [
            5000,
            10000,
            15000,
            30000,
            50000
        ]
    }]

    return options
    .filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.key == key;
    })
    .map(function(obj){
        return obj.values;
    });
}
```

But I get the error:

> Type 'number[][]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
>     Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Ummm did you read the error carefully?

Comment: Return type is number[][]

Comment: In your map you probably want to `return obj.values[0];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter will return an array of matches, so in this example you get an array with one item in it. You are then taking that array result and using map on it to return an array result as well, which is why you are returning an array of arrays hence the error.

You should use find and perhaps a small error check like this:

```
return (options
    .find(function(obj) {
      return obj.key == key;
    }) || { values: [] }).values
```

Here is a demo:

```js
console.log(([{key:5, values: [1]}].find(function(obj) {
      return obj.key == 5;
    }) || { values: [] }).values);
console.log(([{key:6, values: [1]}].find(function(obj) {
      return obj.key == 5;
    }) || { values: [] }).values);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it works like a charm, I will accept the answer as soon as it becomes available

Answer (score 0):

Your return value is a 2D array, but you're declaring your method's return value to be a flat array of numbers.  Your .filter and .map methods are being called on the "outer" array, the value of `options`.

After your .filter call, the return value is the same as the value of `options`; you've iterated through `options` and returned each object that has a key value.

After your .map call, the return value is an array that contains "all" the values of each `values` prop on each object in that array.

A simple fix for your return statement:

```
return options
.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.key == key;
})
.reduce(function(accum, obj){
  return [...accum, ...obj.values || []];
}, []);
```

That should give you the return value of:

`[5000, 10000, 15000, 30000, 50000]`

This is assuming you would want to concatenate the arrays if there were multiple objects in `options` with the same key...